# Cannot call method "showRows" of null

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the rows when column G will be 0. I tried with this code I found in Internet but it always has an error: TypeError: Cannot call method "showRows" of null. 
Could someone help me?
The code is:

```
function onOpen() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName('Orders Quantities');
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
    sheet.getRange('G:G')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
                .charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(i + 1)
        });
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear over there: `s` is null, which means `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Orders Quantities');` is null, so there's probably no sheet named `'Orders Quantities'`.

Answer (score 1):

That means that `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Orders Quantities');` probably returns null and not an `Object`.

You could check the object for `null` before processing it or make sure it does not return `null` (probably there is no spreadsheet called 'Orders Quantities' here).

*I would love to just comment, yet somehow comments require more reputation than answers (why is that)?*